# Different version of GlobalOptions package in R

Tags: r, version, updates, install.packages, circlize

I'm trying to install the package "circlize" and I am having trouble resolving what seems to be a simple error.

When I run:

```
install.packages("circlize")
```

It says:

```
Installing package into ‘*file location*/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘GlobalOptions’ is not available

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
circlize 0.3.10  0.4.3             FALSE

installing the source package ‘circlize’

trying URL 'https://mirrors.sorengard.com/cran/src/contrib/circlize_0.4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2456906 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

* installing *source* package 'circlize' ...
** package 'circlize' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'GlobalOptions' 0.0.11 is being loaded, but >= 0.0.12 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'circlize'
* removing '*file location*/3.2/circlize'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"*file location*/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "*file location*\3.2" *file location*/downloaded_packages/circlize_0.4.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘circlize’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘*file location*\downloaded_packages’
```

These parts seem most relevant to me:

> dependency ‘GlobalOptions’ is not available
>
> namespace 'GlobalOptions' 0.0.11 is being loaded, but >= 0.0.12 is required

When I run **sessionInfo()** I see under "other attached packages": [1] GlobalOptions_0.0.11

My best guess is that I have the wrong version of GlobalOptions -- I see that GlobalOptions v0.0.13 is available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GlobalOptions/index.html), but being new to R, I'm not sure what to do now to get the right version up and running.

I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me where I should look next. (I looked through the documentation within that link, but I'm still lost about what to do now.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have R version `>=3.3.0` you should

- install `GlobalOptions_0.0.13` from CRAN

  ```
  install.packages("GlobalOptions")
  ```
- quit and restart R
- re-install `circlize` from source as before.

If you have an older R version, update R to a more recent version first.